# Selecting HTML content from nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a javascript/jQuery Hangman-like game, and I have a problem with selecting HTML content from the virtual keyboard keys :

```
<div class="square keyboard">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                Q
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, this is one key from a virtual keyboard that shows up on the screen. I want to write a function that will check which letter was clicked (I know that this structure is too complicated for a simple button on a keyborad, but i wanted it to be responsive, eg. size of buttons would change based on the device  and that was the best i came up with). Here's my code:

```
function isClicked($param){

    var letter = $param.text()
    console.log(letter) //just to check what has been pressed
}
```

Then i put that function here:

```
$('.keyboard').click(function() {
    isClicked($(this));
})
```

The problem is, when I click a key I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8I0g.png) and of course when I compare it to a letter 'Q' it returns False. I tried .html() instead of .text(), it returned actual html code of the button, fiddled with .find(), .filter() and other functions, it usually returned "undefined". What should I do to get just the letter?
PS. I can't insert the letter inside `<p></p>` because it messes key layout, the letter is then slightly too high compared to the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.keyboard.table-cell').on('click', isClicked);
```

Will work when you change your isClicked function to

```
function isClicked(){ 
  var letter = $(this).text().trim(); 
  console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: well, it almost works. I get the letter Q but still moved to the right as if it was indented couple of times. After using .trim() everything is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [String.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to trim the whitespace around the letter.

```
var letter = $param.text().trim()
```

But it's generally better to use attributes for this kind of things, like setting `data-letter="Q"` on the element and then using `$(this).data('letter')` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var letter = $param.text().trim()`

```js
function isClicked($param){

    var letter = $param.text().trim()
    console.log('Q') //just to check what has been pressed
}


$('.keyboard').click(function() {
    isClicked($(this));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square keyboard">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                Q
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```